# What must I enter into Terminal, using sudo to make myself an administrator?

Tags: macos, terminal, user-account, administrator

My user account is a standard account on my Mac. What must I enter into Terminal using `sudo`, to make myself the administrator?

Comment: Is this about permanently changing your user account, or about running a terminal session with the rights of an admin (or root) user for which you know the logon info?

Answer (score 14):

If the actual user *< user_name >* has a standard account, you would have to enter

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership <user_name>
```

to make *< user_name >* an admin.

Only a restricted number of users are *sudoers* (i.e. accounts which are allowed to run `su` or `sudo` with root privileges successfully) though. The standard sudoers file (*/etc/sudoers*) in OS X looks like this:

```
...
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) ALL
...
```

So only *root* and members of the admin group are allowed to run `sudo` by default. The above command run by *< user_name >* will fail consequently, because  *< user_name >* isn't in the list.

To enable *sudoing* for *< user_name >*, you would have to add *< user_name >* to the list (below *# User privilege specification*) or uncomment the %wheel line with `sudo visudo` which has to be run by *sudoers* again (that's the Catch22 mentioned by Tetsujin).

Comment: Nicely specific to counter my 'wonderfully vague'. +1, as always.

Comment: I don't recall: didn't the latest OSX rev. include some sort of "not-really-sudo" that lacks full standard Unix su rights?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yep, you're probably thinking about [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

Answer (score 12):

That's a bit of a Catch22…

You need to already **be** an administrator to be on the sudoers list [with very few manually-changed exceptions]

Essentially, you cannot promote yourself.
That's the entire point of sudo & being an administrator, to be able to assign non-admins limited abilities.

Answer (score -2):

If you have access to an administrator account, you can become that account temporarily with:

```
su - <admin_username>
```

From there you can perform administrative actions via `sudo`.

If you do not have access to an administrator account, then there is no "sanctioned" way of getting admin access (since that's the whole point to having separate admin roles), but there are plenty of less-than-legitimate ways of attaining it, such as privilege escalation exploits or booting into single-user mode. (These will be left as an exercise to the reader.)